# How to disable the screenshot sound?

Tags: settings, screenshot

So, one of the sound effects that I don't like is the screenshot sound with the elementary screenshot app when you press the printscreen key. I found out that disabling the "Play sound" tick from the event alerts in sound settings disables some of the sound effects, like the file deletion sound from the file manager which I also didn't like, but that option still didn't disable the screenshot sound. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!